# User control using panel and labels dynamically added horizontally

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to create a user control using a Windows Forms `Panel` and number of `Label`s with some text dynamically added to the `Panel` horizontally. I am trying with below code and the `Label`s get overridden.

```
public partial class AllergyBar : Panel
{
    public AllergyBar()
        : base()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    int X = 0, Y=0;

    int height, width;
    public AllergyBar(List<String> lstAlerts)
        : base()
    {

        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.WhiteSmoke;
        this.Name = "panel2";
        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
        foreach (string alert in lstAlerts)
        {
            Label AllergyLabel = new Label();
            AllergyLabel.Text = alert;
            width = AllergyLabel.Size.Width;
            Y = AllergyLabel.Location.Y;
            AllergyLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(X+width, Y);
            AllergyLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            AllergyLabel.AutoSize = true;
            AllergyLabel.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            AllergyLabel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            this.Controls.Add(AllergyLabel);
        }       
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use FlowLayoutPanel https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to update X value at the end of each loop:

```
public partial class AllergyBar : Panel
{
    public AllergyBar(): base()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    int X = 0, Y=0;

    int height, width;
    public AllergyBar(List<String> lstAlerts): base()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.WhiteSmoke;
        this.Name = "panel2";
        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
        foreach (string alert in lstAlerts)
        {
            Label AllergyLabel = new Label();
            AllergyLabel.Text = alert;
            AllergyLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(X, Y);
            AllergyLabel.AutoSize = true;
            AllergyLabel.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            AllergyLabel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            X += AllergyLabel.Width;
            this.Controls.Add(AllergyLabel);
        }
    }
}
```